# Why does the Scanner not read the first line in which i call the programm?

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I'm pretty new to programming and i have to do a programm in which i get an undefined amount of integers. The first 2 integers are the size of 2D-Array. And i fill the array with the remaining integers. For Example java Matrix 2 2 0 1 0 1. So the Array size should be 2x2 and 0 1 0 1, but the problem is the scanner doesnt read the integers. If i use java Matrix and put the integers into the next line it works. The problem is i have to put the integers into the first line.

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
String a = "";

while(sc.hasNextInt()){
 a = a + sc.nextInt();
 a = a + " ";
}
```

This is the part of my code i use to read the integers and put them into one string. 
I would really appreciate some ideas how i could change it.

Comment: Command line arguments are passed in `String[] args` to `main`; they are not readable from `System.in`; can you do `java Matrix < 2 2 0 1 0 1`?

Comment: Oh ok so thats the problem, i didnt know that its not readable. Thank you for you help. I changed it so i save the arguments from args in a different string and put them together later on.

Answer (score 0):

You can use use a scanner with `nextInt` to read every single integer from user. Then use a nested for loop to insert the values into the 2D-Array.

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.print("Enter input: ");
int row = in.nextInt();
int column = in.nextInt();
int[][] matrix = new int[row][column]; //initialize matrix with row and column entered by user
for(int r = 0; r <row; r++) {   //nested for loop to insert values from user into matrix
    for(int c = 0; c < column; c++) {
        matrix[r][c] = in.nextInt();
    }
}
for(int[] array : matrix) {    //print matrix
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array));
}
```

Console

```
Enter input: 2 2 0 1 0 1
[0, 1]
[0, 1]
```